# Dense_rank and sum

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have this common table expression

```
WITH total_hour
AS (
    SELECT 
      employee_id,
      SUM(ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, finish_time) AS NUMERIC(18, 0)) / 60, 2)) AS total_h
    FROM Timesheet t
    WHERE t.employee_id = @employee_id
      AND DENSE_RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, '20130925', date_worked) / 7 DESC ) = @rank
    GROUP BY t.personnel_id
    )
```

This is the sample data:

```
ID  employee_id     worked_date     start_time      finish_time
 1     1          2013-09-25        09:00:00    17:30:00        
 2     1          2013-09-26        07:00:00    17:00:00    
 8     1          2013-10-01        09:00:00    17:00:00    
 9     1          2013-10-04        09:00:00    17:00:00    
 12    1          2013-10-07        09:00:00    17:00:00    
 13    1          2013-10-30        09:00:00    17:00:00    
 14    1          2013-10-28        09:00:00    17:00:00    
 15    1          2013-11-01        09:00:00    17:00:00
```

Supposed Wednesday is the first day of the week and my based date is 2013-09-25. I want to get the total number of hours worked from 09-25 to 10-01 when @rank is 1 and total hour from 10-02 to 10-08 when @rank=2 and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Posting a query and telling us that it doesn't work, does not really give us any useful information about what your problem is...

Comment: Hello Dan, this is what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to calculate the total time an employee has worked in a particular week. Based on the query above, the SUM function will return the total number of hours worked by this employee from the beginning of time. However, I want only the total number of hours for particular week only. I will edit my first post. Please have a look. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of hours worked for an employee within a particular week, just use a suitable WHERE criteria. No need to use DENSE_RANK or similar windowed functions for this.

Assuming you have a @Week parameter, that contains an integer (0 for current week, 1 for last week, 2 for week before that, etc.):

```
SELECT
    employee_id
    SUM(ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, finish_time) AS NUMERIC(18, 0)) / 60, 2)) AS total_h
FROM
    Timesheet t
WHERE
    t.employee_id = @employee_id AND
    date_worked BETWEEN DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()) - @Week, 0)
                    AND DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()) - @Week, 0) + 7
```

Here, I've used the current date (`GETDATE()`) as the base date, but you could just replace it with `20130925`, if that's what you need.

Comment: Hello Dan, thanks for the help. I think the query above use Sunday as the first day of the week. What if Wednesday is the first day of the week?

Comment: Use SET DATEFIRST to specify which day is your first day of week, like this: `SET DATEFIRST 3`, will make Wednesday the first day of week. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx for more information.

Comment: Dan, one last thing, when I change the GetDate() to '20130925', nothing is returned. Here is my query:

Comment: SET DATEFIRST 3
  SELECT
    employee_id,
    SUM(ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, finish_time) AS NUMERIC(18, 0)) / 60, 2)) AS total_h
FROM
    Timesheet t
WHERE
    t.employee_id = 1 AND
    date_worked BETWEEN DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'20130925') - 2, 0)
                    AND DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'20130925') - 2, 0) + 7
     GROUP BY employee_id

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you have any records in the Timesheet table where employee_id = 1 and date_worked between '20130909' and '20130916' ?